# Cannot load an SQLite JDBC Driver, Any Ideas?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

So i need to write a program that accesses and modifies an SQLite DB for a school program and am looking at the basics firstly. Now, I am looking at this to get me started: [link text](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). The problem is that when i compile Test.java (The example code on the website) and then run the command:

```
java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test
```

like it tells me to, i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Test.  Program will exit.
```

Test.java, Test.class and sqlitejdbc-v056.jar are all in the same folder so they should find each other. Does anybody have an idea about what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

According to the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test`, the `Test` class cannot be found in the CLASSPATH. But you wrote that `Test.class` is available in the current directory so I'm gonna guess something. Actually, I think that you are not using the right CLASSPATH separator character (which is platform dependent) and thus not building correctly the CLASSPATH. On Windows, you should use `;` instead of `:`. If this happens to be the case, you should try this:

```
java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test
```

If you are on a unix-like platform, forget this answer, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem, Much appreciated.

Was just wondering though, What is the difference between these:
        java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test
        java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test.class
Because when i put the ".class" at the end, I get errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem, Much appreciated. Was just wondering though, What is the difference between these two commands: "java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test" and then "java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test.class" Because when i put the ".class" at the end, I get errors. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Regarging `java -cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test.class`, this is just not how you invoke a class with `java`. The `java` command takes the *Name of the class to be invoked* as argument (Test), not a file (Test.class).

Answer (score 1):

As the exception message is saying, the problem is that it cannot find the class Test.  So the problem is not finding SQLite, but finding your Test class.

Just a guess, but I am wondering if there is an issue with how you compiled.  In the Test.java, does the class belong to a package?  If so, you need to compile it using the -d flag so that it gets put in the appropriate sub-directory.